# Convert MTS to MPEG

Tags: mp4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting panasonic .MTS video into high quality mpeg videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45025/converting-panasonic-mts-video-into-high-quality-mpeg-videos)

I have a Sony handycam which records HD videos in AVCHD resulting in .MTS file names. The video doesnt play properly in Movie Player & VLC Player with frames getting stuck in the middle randomly.

How do I convert them to MPEG (MPEG-2, MP4 ?) format assuming there is no loss in quality during conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was originally posted at: [How to convert a mp4 video to MPEG-1 Layer 1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65146/how-to-convert-a-mp4-video-to-mpeg-1-layer-1/65158#65158)

> Take a look at this answer:
>   [How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files/25532#25532)
>   Which may be helpful for understanding the transcoding process.
>
> There are several GUI's that are able to perform this task, which
>   includes but not limits to:
>
> ## [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm)
>
> [image]
>
> ## [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/)
>
> [image]
>
> And [many more](http://alternativeto.net/software/handbrake/?platform=linux).
>
> My favorite is the Mobile Media Converter but I have used the WinFF,
>   Transmaggedon, Arista Transcoder, and many more in the past with
>   excellent results.
>
> Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of conversion options, but they're all based on the same ffmpeg libraries. If they don't play in movie player or VLC, it's not certain that conversion will help.

In any case, you can look at:

- Handbrake (https://edge.launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases)
- avidemux
- mencoder

I'd recommend them in that order.