problem converting .mts video to usable format (mp4, m4v, etc)
My PVR makes '.mts' and '.mts.META' files for each video, and trying to use handbrake to convert the '.mts' file to say '.m4v' results in unusable video. Trying to play '.mts' file with say VLC produces choppy video that hangs a lot and appears corrupted...and they play fine on my PVR which created them - also play fine via the USB port on my Blu-ray player. My samsung smart TV's USB port doesn't recognize the file's format.
Tried to use '4K Video Converter | Formatlab' but installed and no launcher, or force launch and get error message 'Unable to find "*/snap/Snap Store/io.snapcraft.formatlab-UGNrnY8V0iJd8uSYC99HUKwM2eVzlpvN/latest/stable" '... finally DID get it to run ~ but creates choppy, hanging, unusable video over 5 hours long from a 1-hr video :-?
Any 'reliable' video converter out there for this type of video format?
Tried several online converters which result in same unusable mess. Even tried VLC both linux and windoz - more junk. Downloaded one microslop program which made file that wouldn't even play:-(

This answer was useful. https://askubuntu.com/a/45030/1672204 [Converting panasonic .MTS video into high quality mpeg videos?]

https://askubuntu.com/a/45030/1672204 is over 13 years old, points to a website that gets blocked, etc. and suggests handbrake which doesn't work on this issue...

ffmpeg?
not good at these terminal command line options... was looking for some GUI user friendly version... preferably free for more than 5 days :-}

...found WinFF and tried it (GUI for ffmpeg) and got same unusable video as handbrake - makes a 1 hour video into an over 5 hour one that hangs after a while of very choppy junk.
gonna look at my win7 partition and try something there?

WIN7 was useless - a lot online/download out there for it saying will convert mts, but ya get to the input file file formats list and no mts there, only thing close is m2ts... scrap!

@TheMAJOR Can you post a sample of one of these videos is a publicly accessible place?

What does ffprobe output for one of the files?

don't know how to use ffprobe...which 'option' should I use?
ffprobe [OPTIONS] INPUT_FILE

The Video LAN forum (VLC) pretty much indicates: even though the .mts file plays fine on my HD-PVR and Blu-Ray player, the files have "synchronization" issues in 'other' players and diagnostic tools making it so there's no way to convert to m4v, mp4, avi, mov, etc.

"@TheMAJOR Can you post a sample of one of these videos is a publicly accessible place? – andrew.46"
....no.
(the file is almost one gigabyte...)
